# Do I need to release IplImage after conversion to Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks

I do the following in couple of places in my code;

```
cv::Mat cv_proc_image = ...
IplImage ipl_img = cv_proc_image;
cvSmooth(&ipl_img, &ipl_img, smooth_type, smooth_param1);
cv_proc_image = cv::cvarrToMat(&ipl_img);
```

And I observe memory bloating after the changes inclding this operation. Do you think, should I release the memory allocated by IplImages after the last assignment?

Comment: what is cv_proc_image?

Comment: it is cv::Mat  taken from function argument

Comment: You shouldn't use old C syntax in the first place

Comment: if you show what `smooth_type` and `smooth_param1` are, I can provide a small example in my answer to show how to use C++ syntax

Comment: is there any benefit of using `cvSmooth` instead of `cv::Smooth`?

Comment: does `IplImage ipl_img = cv_proc_image;` allocate new memory? if yes then you'll have to free it yourself

Comment: @Micka no new memory allocations. Check updated answer ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use old C syntax in the first place. You should use C++ syntax. Also note that [cvSmooth](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#smooth):

> The function is now obsolete. Use GaussianBlur(), blur(), medianBlur() or bilateralFilter().

---

**UPDATE**

When you do `IplImage ipl_img = mat_img;` you're just creating a new header, no copies of data. So this **is not** draining your memory. Let me show it with a small example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Your (green) mat
    Mat mat_img(10, 10, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,255,0));

    // To IplImage
    IplImage ipl_img = mat_img;
```

Both `mat_img` and `ipl_img` are equals. No copy involved.

[image]

```
    // It's created only a new header, on the same data

    // In fact, changing ipl_img changes also mat_img
    cvSet2D(&ipl_img, 1, 2, Scalar(255,0,0));
```

Both images changed to this:

[image]

```
    // Same here, changing ipl_img changes also mat_img
    cvSmooth(&ipl_img, &ipl_img);

    return 0;
}
```

Even after smoothing they are equal:

[image]

**Conclusion**

So to answer your original question: **NO**, you don't need to release the `IplImage`, since no copies are involved. You're just creating new headers, but pointing to the same data. Your memory leaks are somewhere else.

You don't even need to use `cvarrToMat`, since the changes to the `IplImage` are the same as in the `Mat`.

Comment: This is not the best place for this discussion but it is worth noting that the op didn't mention what version of OpenCV he is using or whether or not this is legacy code. We need to be mindful as a community that questions may still arise from developers of older systems. Now whether or not this isn't still the correct response I don't know, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I partially agree with you. Clearly OP is not in a C environment, otherwise he couldn't use `Mat`. So it's C++. For the same reason, the version is quite quite new. In any case, I left comments to the question, if he **must** use C, then I expect a response from him. Also, in the posted code he's just using old syntax to call a single function, and then  back to new syntax. This shows that using new syntax also for the function the problem will be solved (my other comment is about giving a complete example). So I think this **does** answer the question, at least as it is stated _now_ @GPPK

Comment: That told me! I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: @GPPK since _I partially agree with you_, I've answered also the main question. Thanks for pointing this out in the first place.

Comment: Do you think this might be the reason? cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(new_width, new_height));

Comment: @Erogol no, this won't cause leaks per se. Please post a mcve that shows the leak, so we can investigate further.

Comment: Yes you say so but after I changed it to cv::resize(img, dst, cv::Size(new_width, new_height)), my memory consumption goes drastically down. I rely on http://answers.opencv.org/question/16059/opencv-resize-memory-leak/

Comment: @Erogol `resize` creates a new matrix if sizes are not the same. So if you are working on shared data (as in the case of the `IplImage`) then you have this problem. That's why I asked for a mcve, I don't know which code you're using. The problem is not in the `resize` itself, but on the underlying _shared_ data.

Answer (score 0):

from Opencv Documentation:

```
>     When copyData=false , the conversion is done really fast (in O(1) time) and the newly created matrix header will have refcount=0 , which
> means that no reference counting is done for the matrix data. In this
> case, you have to preserve the data until the new header is
> destructed. Otherwise, when copyData=true , the new buffer is
> allocated and managed as if you created a new matrix from scratch and
> copied the data there. That is, cvarrToMat(arr, true) is equivalent to
> cvarrToMat(arr, false).clone() (assuming that COI is not set). The
> function provides a uniform way of supporting CvArr paradigm in the
> code that is migrated to use new-style data structures internally. The
> reverse transformation, from Mat to CvMat or IplImage can be done by a
> simple assignment:
```

In your case you did not set 'copyData' so it is false by default:

```
Mat cvarrToMat(const CvArr* arr, bool copyData=false, bool allowND=true, int coiMode=0 )
```

So, you have to release it by yourself.

Edit:
I am not familiar with old OpenCV style.. does lplimage free it self when get out of scope? if it does so no leak should happen

Comment: IplImage doesn't free when it goes out of scope. The question is, whether `IplImage ipl_img = cv_proc_image;` allocates new memory or whether the data pointer of `cv_proc_image` is used somewhere internally in the IplImage. If new memory is allocated there, then he has to free it manually.